# Spring Data JPA Sorting: How to make a link on the view to switch between ascending and descending?

Tags: sorting, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I'm currently struggling a little bit with implementing a nice Link in the header of my table to sort a certain column. I want the link to dynamically determine if the current sorting value is Ascending or Descending, and then set it accordingly. Currently I only have it set to sort to Ascending:

```
<a href="<@spring.url '?page=${page.number+1}&size=${page.size}&sort=title,asc'/>">
Site Name
</a>
```

What I cannot figure out is how to determine the current sorting order?
The page object has a getSort() method, which returns a Sort object. The Sort object has a getOrderOf(String Property) method, which should return the sorting order. But how to implement this properly in my template?

Ideally want something like this:

```
<a href="<@spring.url '?page=${page.number+1}&size=${page.size}&sort=title,${sortOrder}'/>">
Site Name
</a>
```

But would be happy to start with a more verbose mode:

```
<#if sortOrder==DESC>
    <a href="<@spring.url '?page=${page.number+1}&size=${page.size}&sort=title,asc'/>">
    Site Name
    </a>
<#else>
    <a href="<@spring.url '?page=${page.number+1}&size=${page.size}&sort=title,desc'/>">
    Site Name
    </a>
</#if>
```

Could not find too much relevant info on this subject so far. Just need something to get started.

Thanks,
Joachim

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what template language you're using, but here's how to do it in JSP/JSTL.

`/WEB-INF/tags/statefulQuery.tag`:

```
<%@ tag pageEncoding="UTF-8" trimDirectiveWhitespaces="true" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ attribute name="name" required="true" type="java.lang.String" %>
<%@ attribute name="value" required="true" type="java.lang.String" %>

<c:url value="">

    <%-- if $name in query then replace its value with $value. copy others --%>
    <c:forEach items="${param}" var="p">
        <c:param name="${p.key}" value="${p.key == name ? value : p.value}"/>
    </c:forEach>

    <%-- if $name is not in query, then add it --%>
    <c:if test="${empty param[name]}">
        <c:param name="${name}" value="${value}"/>
    </c:if>

</c:url>
```

Usage:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="my" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" %>

<!-- sort links -->
<a href="<my:statefulQuery name='sort' value='name${page.sort.getOrderFor("name").ascending? ",desc" : "" }' />">Name</a>
<a href="<my:statefulQuery name='sort' value='price${page.sort.getOrderFor("price").ascending? ",desc" : "" }' />">Price</a>


<!-- pager links -->
<a href="<my:statefulQuery name='page' value='${page.previousPageable().pageNumber}'/>">&lsaquo;</a>
<a href="<my:statefulQuery name='page' value='${page.nextPageable().pageNumber}'/>">&rsaquo;</a>
```